# Etymology of the word "function" in mathematics

Tags: terminology, math-history

What is the etymology of the word "function" (i.e. a map) in mathematics. How does (historically) the etymology of the word function relate to the mathematical definition and the mathematical concept of a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word comes directly from Latin *functio*, which means *performance* or *execution*. See [the entry in the Lewis-Short dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=functio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) and also [the entry for *fungor*, the related verb](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=fungor&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059). In other words, a *functio* is the performance or execution of a task (a set of algebraic operations on a quantity, initially).

As far as I know it was Leibniz to use it (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_function_concept#The_notion_of_.22function.22_in_analysis) and the term became popular with the Bernoullis and Euler, who introduced the $f(x)$ notation.